# Error: Unterminated string literal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-form

I have some HTML data that's generated from `Zend_Form`.

I want to append it to the `div#wrapper` element, but my attempt is provoking an error: `Unterminated string literal`.

What should I do to fix it?

**NOTE:** okay everyone look like assume me forgot to put php tag on my code but it doesn't. Here is my 'real' code

```
<?php

class Admin_Elements_Dialog {
private $_name;
private $_title;
private $_action;
private $_button = null;
private $_content;
private $_options = array();

public function __construct($options) {
    $this->_options = $options;        
}

public function setName($name) {
    $this->_name = $name;

    return $this;    
}

public function setTitle($title) {
    $this->_title = $title;

    return $this;    
}

public function setAction($action) {
    $this->_action = $action;

    return $this;    
}

public function setOpener($button) {
    if ($button instanceof Admin_Elements_Buttons)
        $this->_button = $button;

    return $this;    
}

public function setContent($content) {
    $this->_content = $content;

    return $this;
}

public function renderScript() {
    $html = array();

    $html[] = '$(document).ready(function() {
                    $("body").append(\'<div id="' . $this->_name . '" title="' . $this->_title . '" class="ui-helper-hidden">' . $this->_content . '</div>\');

                    var dialog = $("#' . $this->_name . '").dialog(' . Zend_Json::encode($this->_options, false, array('enableJsonExprFinder' => true)) . '); 

                    $("#' . $this->_button->getId() . '").click(function() {
                        $("#' . $this->_name . '").dialog("open");

                        return false;
                    });
                });';

    $html[] = '';

    return join($html, PHP_EOL);    
}
}
?>
```

Comment: He's mixing PHP and Javascript so it does..

Comment: @Tomalak: sorry for my bad english, peace gan

Comment: Sensitivity to string instruments notwithstanding, if you solved your problem post the solution as an answer, not an edit.

Comment: yeah, i must wait for the next 5 hours to do it :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i solved my problem by remove of all new lines and page breaks with function preg_replace

```
preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', null, $this->_content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the PHP concatenation operator `.` in Javascript.

Javascript's concatenation operator is `+`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("div#wrapper").append('<div id="dialog" title="Add new blog">' + <?php echo $this->form->render() ?> + '</div>');
});
```

Further, PHP code is *inserted* into your page verbatim. If `$this->form->render()` doesn't produce a literally quote-encapsulated string, then the resulting Javascript will be invalid.

You might mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("div#wrapper").append('<div id="dialog" title="Add new blog"><?php echo $this->form->render() ?></div>');
});
```

But there are definitely better approaches. This way, you'll have to watch out for escapable characters and newlines.

<sub>Also, I couldn't resist: it's "thanks in advance"; no trailing "d".</sub>

Comment: This still won't work. You need to wrap `<?php ?>` around `$this->form->render()` because that is PHP code. The other option is enclose the entire JQuery script in quotes and `echo` in PHP.

Comment: @ThiefMaster @Brice: Obvious copy/paste fail. Typo fixed.

Comment: Ok, there *is* more than that. Fixed.

Comment: @brian: You put it, and I removed it. In hindsight, it possibly _does_ belong on the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing PHP and JavaScript code. You always need to keep in mind that PHP runs on the server and Javascript on the client.

What you want is probably this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("div#wrapper").append('<div id="dialog" title="Add new blog"><?php echo $this->form->render(); ?></div>');
});
```

Obviously you need to ensure that all linebreaks and single quotes in that string are escaped (`\n` and `\'`)

Comment: Obviously the script is generated in PHP class on function renderScript

Comment: That is just a small part of them

Answer (score 0):

You mix javascript and PHP code.

I think this could be better if your js is generated by a PHP script :

```
  <?php /** I'm in PHP */ ?>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("div#wrapper").append('<div id="dialog" title="Add new blog"><?php $this->form->render()?></div>');
   });
```

Comment: you forgot about echoing after render the form :d

Comment: I don't know if the render return a string or display something.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is parsed on the server side before Javascript is run on the client side. Therefore, the PHP will be injected directly in the Javascript string. Then JQuery will append it where you specify.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("div#wrapper").append('<div id="dialog" title="Add new blog"><?php echo $this->form->render() ?></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when your PHP code renders on the server, it parses everything in between `<?php ?>`. So when your code renders, it gets something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#wrapper").append('<div id="dialog" title="Add new blog">' + <form></form> + '</div>');
});
```

Notice that the resulting JS code has a `<form></form>` element that is not enclosed in quotes. This gets you the "unterminated string literal" error.

To fix that, you just need to enclose the thing in quotes, like

```
$("div#wrapper").append(
    '<div id="dialog" title="Add new blog">' + '<?php $this->form->render(); ?>' + '</div>'
)
```

Alternatively, you can chuck the PHP into your JS string:

```
$("div#wrapper").append(
    '<div id="dialog" title="Add new blog"><?php $this->form->render(); ?></div>'
)
```